# Java Observer Pattern issue?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have the following Observer:

```
public class Fisc implements Observer {
double value1;
double value2;
private static HashMap<String, Deposit> accounts=new HashMap<String,Deposit>();
public Fisc(String cnp,Deposit deposit) {

    System.out.println("\n*******Observer*******Watching account:"+id);
    accounts.put(id, deposit);

}

public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
    if (arg instanceof Deposit) {
        value1 =((Deposit) arg).getvalue1();
        value2=((Deposit) arg).getvalue2();
        System.out.println("\n*******Observer*******value1 current value:"+value1);
        System.out.println("*******Observer*******value2 current value:"+value2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Observable error!");
    }
}
}
```

and the Observable:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Observable;


public class obs extends Observable {

    private static HashMap<String, Deposit> accounts;

    private static obs instance;

    private obs(HashMap<String,Deposit> accounts){
        obs.accounts=accounts;
    }

    public static obs getInstance(){
        if (instance==null){
            return new obs(new HashMap<String,Deposit>());
        }
        else return instance;
    }

        // ... some unimportant other stuff

    public void depositvalue1(String id,double value1){
        Deposit deposit=accounts.get(id);
        deposit.addvalue1(value1);

        if(deposit.isWatchedByFisc()){
            notifyFisc(deposit);
        }
        System.out.println("obs:Deposited "+value1+ " value1 to account:"+id+"!");
        System.out.println("obs:Current value1 in account:"+deposit.getvalue1());
    }

    public void depositvalue2(String id,double value2){
        Deposit deposit=accounts.get(id);
        deposit.addvalue2(value2);

        if(deposit.isWatchedByFisc()){
            notifyFisc(deposit);
        }

        System.out.println("obs:Deposited "+value2+" value2 to account:"+id+"!");
        System.out.println("obs:Current value1 in account:"+deposit.getvalue2());
    }

    public void depositValues(String id,double value1,double value2){
        Deposit deposit=accounts.get(id);
        deposit.addvalue1(value1);
        deposit.addvalue2(value2);

        if(deposit.isWatchedByFisc()){
            notifyFisc(deposit);
        }

        System.out.println("obs:Deposited "+value1+ " value1 and "+value2+" value2 to account"+id+"!");
        System.out.println("obs:Current value1 in account:"+deposit.getvalue1());
    }

    public void watchAccount(String id){
        Deposit deposit=accounts.get(id);
        deposit.setWatchedByFisc(true);
        addObserver(new Fisc(id,deposit));
    }

    public void stopWatchAccount(String id){
        accounts.get(id).setWatchedByFisc(false);
        System.out.println("obs:Account "+id+" is no longer watched by Fisc!");
    }

    public void notifyFisc(Deposit deposit){
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(deposit);
    }

}
```

Everything works as suppossed except the following: If I use the `depositValue(1,2,s)` methods instead of getting the message once, I get the same message the number of times I have registered deposits to be watched. How can I fix this?

> Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a stupid question this is the first time using Observer Pattern.

My guess is this line maybe(multiple instances?): `addObserver(new Fisc(id,deposit));`

Comment: I would step through your code in a debugger to see why it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: Where is the code for the `Fisc` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every* observer (an instance of `Fisc`) is notified whenever a `Deposit` instance has changed. So with your code, every `Fisc` has to look at the notification message and check, if it is about *its* deposit.

If you don't want that, then you should make the `Deposit` observable (instead of observing the whole *bank*). Then you can register listeners to individual deposits.

Comment: This was the thing to do except that at an conceptual level, my obs has to notify things but it's ok as I have no other way around it.

Answer (score 1):

You have lumped together all accounts in the same `Observable` object and that's why you get 
notified once for each account.

A better model would probably be to introduce an `Account` class and make that `Observable`.
 
I suggest something like:

```
public class Account extends Observable {

    private String id;    
    private BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal("0.0");

    public Account(String id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deposit(BigDecimal amount) {
        balance = balance.add(amount);
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void withdraw(BigDecimal amount) {
        balance = balance.subtract(amount);
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Your `obs` class would then contain a list of `Account`s:

```
private Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<String, Account>();
```

Note that this class uses BigDecimal for representing the balance, since it is [not recommended to use floating point numbers for it](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=213).